# Grid In scrollviewer

Tags: wpf, grid, scrollview

- i used a GroupBox with a scrollviewer inside it ..and inside scrollviewer i put a grid and begin to put my controls (3 textblocks and 6 textboxes)
  -after making my scrollviewer to scroll my content (the remaining 3 textboxes) i faced a trouble of grid inside scrollviewer appear behind things like the next pic
- how can i make grid have the same size of GroupBox and doesn't appear behind controls??
  [image]

Comment: Can you post your xaml? or a Xaml example

Answer (score 1):

Can you set `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` on the Grid and `VerticalAContentlignment="Stretch"` on the ScrollViewer?

Comment: i followed your advice ..but i still have grid appear behind things ...i even placed controls in 2 stackpanels one for textblocks ,another for textboxes ,and all still appear behind things too